# Question about the associativity of operators in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction

I'd like to ask whether or not quantum operators are associative. Take for example (in one dimension) the momentum operator $\hat{p} = -i \hbar (\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x) $  and the position operator $\hat{x} = x$ acting on some test function $f$ as
$$\hat{p} \hat{x} f(x) \, .$$
Does it make a difference whether the order in which the operators act is $(\hat{p}\hat{x}) f(x)$ or $\hat{p} (\hat{x} f(x))$? For example, in the first case, the derivative from the momentum operator acts on the position operator producing $1$, clearly a different result from the latter case in which the derivatve operator acts on the product $xf(x)$. Does this make the operators non-associative, or am I missing something?

Comment: Your mistake occurs precisely at the point where you say "producing 1".

Answer (score 2):

Composition of differential operators$^1$
$$ (\hat{A} \circ \hat{B}) \circ \hat{C} ~=~\hat{A} \circ (\hat{B} \circ \hat{C}) \tag{1}$$
on the class$^2$ of smooth functions is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), since both the LHS and RHS of eq. (1) is defined by acting on a smooth function $f$ in the same order, namely as
$$ \hat{A}(\hat{B}(\hat{C}(f))). \tag{2} $$

--

$^1$ More generally, [composition of composable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Properties) is associative.

$^2$ For [unbounded operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator), the issue of domains may hamper composition and associativity.

Answer (score 1):

Operators do not act on operators; operators act on states (or wavefunctions, in your example). As such, the order of writing down the operators before a state determines their order of operation. The operator $\hat{x}$ acts on the wavefunction $f(x)$ to produce the wavefunction $xf(x)$. Then the operator $\hat{p}$ acts on the wavefunction $xf(x)$, to produce the wavefunction $-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}(xf(x))$.

Comment: You seem to have a very special context in mind. In particular, in the Heisenberg picture this is certainly not the case, but it is not even entirely correct in the Schrödinger picture.

Comment: @marmot Care to elaborate? I don't see anything wrong with this answer.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Just consider, say. a translation operator and some creation operator that creates something at the position $x$. $\hat{T}_y \hat{a}(x) |-\rangle$, where $\hat{T}_y$ is the operator that generates as translation by $y$. Does it act on the operator or not?

Comment: @marmot In that case, the creation operator acts on the vacuum state to produce a 1-particle state, and the translation operator acts on that resulting 1-particle state.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Wasn't the question about associativity?

Comment: @marmot The concept of associativity is really sort of moot here, which is what I was trying to get across in this answer. This is because $(\hat{p}\hat{x})f(x)=\hat{p}(\hat{x}f(x))$ by definition, because that's the only sensible definition consistent with the fact that operators act on states. You can say this situation demonstrates associativity if and only if you also say that the statement $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$ demonstrates associativity. Most people, I think, consider the latter to be the _definition_ of composition of functions, and so the same should apply here.

Comment: Well, I was just meaning to say that the statement "Operators do not act on operators" needs to be interpreted in a very particular way, and my above example is meant to illustrate why I think that this may be misleading. Do you agree?

Comment: @marmot I don't see how this statement is misleading. The interpretation of your example seems clear.

Comment: In more mathematical terms (but in agreement with the answer), associativity is a property of (binary) relations, not of maps. And an operator is a map. One may ask if product or sum of (bounded) operators are associative, but not if operators thenselves are.