# Question on how to make product rule for differentiation consistent with operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differentiation, notation, calculus

By the product rule for differentiation:$$\frac{\partial(\hat A\psi)}{\partial x}=\left(\frac{\partial\hat A}{\partial x}\right)\psi+\hat A\left(\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\right)\tag{1}$$
Where $\hat A$ is an operator and $\psi$ is a function depend on $x$ i.e. $\psi=\psi(x)$.

My question is: when $\hat A$ takes the form of momentum operator: $\hat A=\hat P=-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, it looks like the product rule for differentiation no longer work (I'm not sure this statement is right or not) since the correct answer should be:
$$\frac{\partial(\hat P\psi)}{\partial x}=-i\hbar\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)\psi-i\hbar\left(\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}\right).$$
It doesn't equal to the answer given by $(1)$.

Another question:
$$\frac{\partial(\psi\hat A)}{\partial t}=\left(\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}\right)\hat A+\psi\left(\frac{\partial\hat A}{\partial t}\right)\tag{2}$$
Where $\hat A$ now takes the form of  $\hat A=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ and $\psi$ is a function depend on $t$ i.e. $\psi=\psi(t)$, then the product rule for differentiation now do works. (I'm pretty sure about this one is correct because it's a derivation from the book.)

I must have confused something. Can someone help me or give me some comments that may correct my question please?

Comment: Possibly related: [Do derivatives of operators act on the operator itself or are they "added to the tail" of operators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451)

Comment: @Qmechanic Oh thank you sooooo much!!

Comment: Note that the time derivative is not an operator on the Hilbert space, tho. So if with $A=\partial /\partial t$ you mean the time derivative, this makes no sense.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thanks for your comment sir! So technically, $H=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ act on Hilbert space but the time derivative dosen't, am I right?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436023/ This similar question helps too

Comment: No, $H=i\hbar \partial/\partial t$ makes no sense! $H$ is an operator on the Hilbert space, the time-derivative is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP is essentially asking how to make sense of
$$\frac{\partial\hat{A}}{\partial x}\tag{i}$$
in OP's eq. (1), where $\hat{A}$ is a differential operator, in particular if $\hat{A}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. The problem is partly that the notation (i) is ambiguous, cf. e.g. [Do derivatives of operators act on the operator itself or are they "added to the tail" of operators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451) In OP's case, the derivative in (i) does not act further, so we can rewrite (i) via Leibniz rule as a commutator
$$ \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\hat{A}\right]\tag{i'}$$
Then OP's eq. (1) turns into a well-known non-commutative Leibniz rule:
$$ \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\hat{A}\psi\right]~=~\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\hat{A}\right]\psi+\hat{A}\underbrace{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\psi\right]}_{=\psi^{\prime}(x)},
\tag{1'}$$
free of notational paradoxes. (Technically, the wavefunction $\psi\leftrightarrow \hat{M}_{\psi}$ is here identified with a zeroth-order differential operator, i.e. a left multiplication operator $\hat{M}_{\psi}\phi:=\psi\phi$.)