# Associativity of covariant derivatives

Tags: general-relativity, operators, differential-geometry, differentiation

I'm having trouble proving that covariant differentiation is an associative operation.
Essentially I'll have to show

$$\nabla_\mu(   \nabla_\nu \nabla_\sigma) = (\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu) \nabla_\sigma. $$

But is it enough to show that both LHS and RHS yield the same result when acted up on a scalar or a contravariant vector?.
Will this hold for any general tensor?
Is there any other method to show this ?

Comment: Related: [Question about the associativity of operators in quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436023/2451)

Comment: A differential operator is technically a function, whose domain and range own functions, and functions associate when they can suitably compose.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the covariant derivation as a bundle-map between the relevant vector bundles of tensors, associativity is automatically guaranteed by the usual associativity of composition of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly it boils down to function/operator composition, which is associative.
Take a general tensor $T^\alpha_\beta$.
$$(\nabla_\nu \nabla_\sigma)T^\alpha_\beta = \nabla_\nu (\nabla_\sigma T^\alpha_\beta )$$
so
$$\nabla_\mu(   \nabla_\nu \nabla_\sigma)T^\alpha_\beta  = \nabla_\mu(\nabla_\nu (\nabla_\sigma T^\alpha_\beta ))$$
Similarly for the right hand side

$$ (\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu) (\nabla_\sigma T^\alpha_\beta)= \nabla_\mu(\nabla_\nu (\nabla_\sigma T^\alpha_\beta ))$$
So both sides of your equation are the same, when expanded.